# display post_thumbnail with older thumbs alternative

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add post_thumbnail support to an old wordpress theme that used to have a custom field for displaying thumbnail images. Trying to combine it as below, so older thumbnails won't get lost.

```
<?php
//display new featured image thumb
      if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
      the_post_thumbnail(homethumb);
}
//use the old thumb if there is no new one
      $customField = get_post_custom_values("post-thumb");
      elseif (isset($customField[0])) { ?>
      <img src="<?php get_custom_field('post-thumb',true); ?>" class="avatar" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<?php
//or use default thumbnail if there is no thumb at all    
} else { ?><img src="<?php echo get_option('theme_post_blankthumb',true); ?>" class="avatar" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /><?php }?>
```

which gives `*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use logical and organized code indentation, you're gonna see clearly where the problem is:

```
<?php
//display new featured image thumb
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
      the_post_thumbnail(homethumb);
}
//use the old thumb if there is no new one
$customField = get_post_custom_values("post-thumb");
elseif (isset($customField[0])) { 
    ?>
        <img src="<?php get_custom_field('post-thumb',true); ?>" class="avatar" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    <?php
//or use default thumbnail if there is no thumb at all    
} else { 
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo get_option('theme_post_blankthumb',true); ?>" class="avatar" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    <?php 
}
```

The line `$customField = get_post_custom_values("post-thumb");` doesn't belong there. Put it before the `if/elseif/else`.

The [**PHP Manual**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) is your friend. And using a good [ide](/questions/tagged/ide) will make your life easier.

Comment: Correct! Figured it out myself a while ago! Thanks Anyway! :D